# How to show that $\{ f_n \}_{n=1}^{\infty} $ is locally uniform convergent, when $f_n (z) = \sum_{k = -n}^{k=n} \frac{1}{z+k} $?

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $D = \mathbb{C} \backslash \mathbb{Z}$. Furthermore, define $f_n : D \to \mathbb{C} $ as: $$ f_n (z) = \sum_{k = -n}^{n} \frac{1}{z+k} ,$$ in which $z \in D$ and $n \in \mathbb{Z}_{>0} $. How do we show that $\{ f_n \}_{n=1}^{\infty} $ converges locally uniform on $D$ ?

I know that a series of functions $f_0 + f_1 + f_2 + \dots + f_n$ is called locally uniformly convergent, when the sequence of partial sums $S_n := f_0 + f_1 + f_2 + \dots $ is locally uniformly convergent.

So here's what I tried: Define $g_n = \frac{1}{z-n} + \frac{1}{z+n} $. Then: $S_n = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} g_n $. We have to show that $S_n$ converges locally uniformly.

But also: $ g_n (z) =  | \frac{1}{z-n} + \frac{1}{z+n} | = | \frac{z+n}{(z+n)(z-n)} + \frac{ z-n}{ (z+n)(z-n) } | = | \frac{2}{z -\frac{n^2}{z} } | .$

But how do I now show that $S_n$ is locally unformly convergent? It seems that convergence tests don't work, and I don't find it not very easy to compare it to, say, $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n^2} .$ What to do next?

Answer (score 1):

Your idea was good, but it's better to write $g_n(z)=\dfrac{2z}{z^2-n^2}$. This denominator can be a problem when $z\approx n$. But when studying convergence, we only need to consider large $n$, and we get to decide what "large" means. For example, we can choose to deal only with $n\ge 2|z|$. In this case 
$$|z^2-n^2| \ge   n^2 -|z|^2 \ge \frac{3}{4}n^2$$
So, the maximum of $|g_n|$ on the disk $|z|\le R$ does not exceed $\dfrac{2R}{\frac34 n^2}$ provided than $n\ge 2R$. The rest should be clear.